# what is the typical size of pre-trained image classification model size

Tags: neural-network, deeplearning4j

I have a few general questions regarding using pre-trained image classification models in mobile.

1. How big is a typical pre-trained model?
2. If it is too big for mobile, what is the best strategy from there?
3. I checked out the documentation of DeepLearning for Java, anywhere to download pre-trained model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's really task dependent. I mean..you can't just say given an unknown problem what is an arbitrary size of neural net.

In general, if you're doing vision expect to be hundreds of megs, but a lot of it comes down tot he activation sizes. I would advise just doing some benchmarking overall. You can't really just handwave that.

A lot of the pretrained models are for computer vision only. They are based on keras. You shouldn't "download" them yourself. No framework works like that.

We have a managed module for that in the model zoo you should use instead.